# 'Manager' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to allow a logged in user to delete their comment under a comment section, but I keep getting the error thrown in the title, and I'm not sure why. I've read up on Managers in the docs but don't quite understand what the issue is, as all my other models work just fine. Here is the code

**views.py**

```
def delete_comment(request, comment_id):

    comment_details = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    # Throws error at this line
    Comment.objects.remove(comment_details)
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('view')
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.comment}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Comment.objects` is an object manager of `Comment` model. To erase the `Comment` object you have already got, you have to `delete()` it:

```
def delete_comment(request, comment_id):
    comment_details = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    comment_details.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('view')
```

Or simpler:

```
def delete_comment(request, comment_id):
    Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('view')
```